# OpenCV Detect scratches on fruits

Tags: python, opencv

For a little experiment in Python I'm doing I want to find small scratches on fruits. The scratches are very small and hard to detect by human eye.

I'm using a high resolution camera for that experiment.

Here is the defect I want to detect:

[image]

Original Image:

[image]

This is my result with very few lines of code:

[image]

So I found the contours of my fruit. How can I proceed to finding the scratch? The RGB Value is similar to other parts of the fruit. So how can I differentiate between A scratch, and a part of the fruit?

My code:

```
# Imports
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

# Read Image & Convert
img = cv2.imread('IMG_0441.jpg')
result = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Filtering
lower = np.array([1,60,50])
upper = np.array([255,255,255])
result = cv2.inRange(result, lower, upper)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(9,9))
result = cv2.dilate(result,kernel)

# Contours
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(result.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
result = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
if len(contours) != 0:
    for (i, c) in enumerate(contours):
        area = cv2.contourArea(c)
        if area > 100000:
            print(area)
            cv2.drawContours(img, c, -1, (255,255,0), 12)
            x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)            
            cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),12)

# Stack results
result = np.vstack((result, img))
resultOrig = result.copy()

# Save image to file before resizing
cv2.imwrite(str(time.time())+'_0_result.jpg',resultOrig)

# Resize
max_dimension = float(max(result.shape))
scale = 900/max_dimension
result = cv2.resize(result, None, fx=scale, fy=scale)

# Show results
cv2.imshow('res',result)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: This is a research problem, how did you conclude that contour detection would be the way to go. The fact that RGB values of the scratch is the same tell you you have to try something different. Personally I would move a gaussian mask over the fruit, extract features, then ry some kind of rudimentary machine learning to identify if a scratch is present or not. not a simple OpenCV task

Comment: Look at this [paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5017387/) They trained a deep neural network to simply detect fruits ripe for harvesting.

Answer (score 2):

I changed your image to HSL colour space.
I can't see the scratch in the L channel, so the greyscale approach suggested earlier is going to be difficult.
But the scratch is quite noticeable in the hue plane.
[image: The scratch is quite noticeable in the hue plane]

You could use an edge detector to find the blemish in the hue channel. Here I use a difference of gaussians detector (with sizes 20 and 4).

[image: DOG]

Comment: yes I do notice the scratch. but what about the rest of the fruit? do you mind to share the code with me? thanks for looking into it!

Answer (score 1):

personal guess is to use some algorithm to detect the grayscale change. The grayscale variation around the scratch should be bigger than the variation in other area. Sobel and Scharr Derivatives could be an option. This is a [link](http://%20https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d5/d0f/tutorial_py_gradients.html) to python-openCV about image gradient. You can first crop out the fruit with coutour application

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use conventional computer vision techniques, you should start with edges that can be detected on the fruit. Some of the edges are caused by the bumps on the fruit, so you have to look at various features of the area around the edges to find the difference between scratches and bumps. After you look at about a hundred scratches, you should be able to come up with some rules.

But this process is going to be very tiring, and my guess is you will not have much luck. A better way to approach this problem is to train a deep neural network by manually annotating scratches on about 100 images, and letting the network find out by itself how to distinguish scratches from the rest of the fruit.

If you are a beginner to these stuff, search for PyImageSearch and LearnOpenCV. Both are very resourceful sites where you can learn quickly.